# The best way how to keep select result in array

Tags: java, arrays, database

I have a question about keeping query result in array. For example I execute a query

`SELECT * FROM some_table`

Then I want to save it to array and create records. The table contains these columns:

- id
- user_name
- last_name

The result array can be:

```
[[1, "First user name", "First last name"],
 [2, "Second user name", "Second last name"]
 ...
].
```

Can you recommend me which array or data type should I use?

Comment: Create your own class and store result into that in list. Read about ORM.

Comment: Thank you for answer. And what if I don't know which columns I have in table? I want to create universal method for getting results to array. What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do that like this:

1. Create a bean class for User

> ```
> public class User {
>    private int id;
>    private String firstName;
>    private String lastName;
>
>    // getter and setter
>    ...
>
> }
> ```

And then query all the data from table, and create a User object and set the data.

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
while(someValue) {
   ...
   int id = ...
   String firstName= ...
   String lastName = ...
   User user = new User();
   user.setId(id);
   user.setFirstName(firstName);
   user.setLastName(lastName);
   users .add(user);
}

// after do what you want with the list
```

Answer (score 0):

I extend your question to "the best way to keep select result" (with or without array).

It depends on:

- how many results
- how many fields
- what do you want to do after ?
- do you want to modify, put in your database again ?

So, several propositions:

- just arrays: String[] fields1; String[] fields2, ...
- array of arrays: String[][];
- better collections: Vector, List or Set: do you want them to be sorted ?, how do you pick them after ?  Or Map, (if you want to keep index => data)
- or Object you create yourself. For this, you even have tools to map object-database.

you should take a look at these features, and what you want to do .

Hope it helps.